# htaccess Redirect using regex

Tags: .htaccess

I Want to redirect some pages as follows

`http://www.example.com/old/thispage1.html` to `http://www.example.com/new/this-page-1.html`

Please suggest.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteRule old/([a-z]*)([0-9]*)\.html new/$1-$2.html
```

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: I never had a look into the apache docs. Contains detailed info. Thanks for that. :)